# Problemas al guardar imágenes usando entity framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, byte

Tengo el siguiente código que con el cual estoy tratando de realizar el guardado de 3 imágenes en una base de datos haciendo uso de entity framework pero al revisar la base de datos no se refleja el guardado del mismo al usar el método save changes

```
 private void btnGuardarPesSeis_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (txtIma1.Text.Trim().Equals(""))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("ARCHIVO OBLIGATORIO: ", "ERROR!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            btupIm1.Select();
        }
        else if (txtIma2.Text.Trim().Equals(""))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("ARCHIVO OBLIGATORIO: ", "ERROR!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            btupIm2.Select();
        }
        else if (txtIma3.Text.Trim().Equals(""))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("ARCHIVO OBLIGATORIO: ", "ERROR!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            btupIm3.Select();
        }
        else
        {
            byte[] file1 = Extraer_Byte();
            byte[] file2 = Extraer_Byte();
            byte[] file3 = Extraer_Byte();

            Guardar_Imagenes(file1, file2, file3);
        }                        
    }
```

El código de extraer_byte es el siguiente:

```
 private byte[] Extraer_Byte()
    {
        Byte[] file = null;
        Stream mystream = openFileDialog1.OpenFile();
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            mystream.CopyTo(ms);
            file = ms.ToArray();
        }

        return file;
    }
```

El método de guardar imágenes.

```
 private static void Guardar_Imagenes(byte[] file1, byte[] file2, byte[] file3)
    {
        try
        {
            using (Model.DS_Entities db = new Model.DS_Entities())
            {
                Model.TBL_HISTORIA_CLINICA oImage = new Model.TBL_HISTORIA_CLINICA();
                oImage.HIS_IMG_1 = file1;
                oImage.HIS_IMG_2 = file2;
                oImage.HIS_IMG_3 = file3;
                db.TBL_HISTORIA_CLINICA.Add(oImage);
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
        }catch(Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("ERROR: " + ex.Message, "ERROR!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }
```

Y por ultimo los códigos de los botones para subir las imágenes

```
 private void btupIm1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        openFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = "c:\\";
        openFileDialog1.Filter = "Archivos jpg (*.jpg)|*.jpg|Archivos png (*.png)|*.png";
        openFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 1;
        openFileDialog1.RestoreDirectory = true;
        if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            txtIma1.Text = openFileDialog1.FileName;
        }
    }

    private void btupIm2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        openFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = "c:\\";
        openFileDialog1.Filter = "Archivos jpg (*.jpg)|*.jpg|Archivos png (*.png)|*.png";
        openFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 1;
        openFileDialog1.RestoreDirectory = true;
        if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            txtIma2.Text = openFileDialog1.FileName;
        }
    }

    private void btupIm3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        openFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = "c:\\";
        openFileDialog1.Filter = "Archivos jpg (*.jpg)|*.jpg|Archivos png (*.png)|*.png";
        openFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 1;
        openFileDialog1.RestoreDirectory = true;
        if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            txtIma3.Text = openFileDialog1.FileName;
        }
    }
```

De antemano agradezco su ayuda y si algo que estoy realizando de manera no correcta por favor les agradezco su feedback.

Comment: Lo que estás queriendo decir es que las imágenes no se guardan en la base de datos?

Comment: exactamente tengo ese problema que no guarda pero creo yo que todo el codigo esta correcto

Comment: Hola, me puedes decir si la respuesta te fue útil, gracias

Comment: Claro, me ayudo con la resolución de mi problema, muchas gracias , un abrazo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En guardar imagen pondrías:

```
Model.TBL_HISTORIA_CLINICA oImage = new Model.TBL_HISTORIA_CLINICA();
oImage.HIS_IMG_1 = File.ReadAllBytes(rutaImagen);
db.TBL_HISTORIA_CLINICA.Add(oImage);
db.SaveChanges();
```

Lo que se hace aquí es usar el **método ReadAllBytes** de la **clase File**, este método recibe un parámetro **string** que es la ruta donde se encuentra la imagen. El método devuelve un **arreglo de bytes**, y este **arreglo de bytes** es el que se guarda en la base de datos.

Para usar el método debes poner en los **usings**:

```
using System.IO;
```

Te explico el ejemplo con una sola imagen(tu tienes 3)

El parámetro **rutaImagen** es la ruta donde se encuentra el fichero, la ruta tendría el siguiente formato por ejemplo: **"C:\Imagenes\Imagen.bmp"**, la ruta podrías obtenerla al abrir un **opendialog**, ej.:

```
rutaImagen = openFileDialog1.FileName;
```